# How do I make it so that a label changes text according to a variable

Tags: c#

I have a label and I want it to display either Player or Console depending on what the variable answer is.

```
    private void playerLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string playerDetail = "Player",
            consoleDetail = "Console";
        if (Class.Method.Variable == 1)
        {
            Show.playerDetail();
        }
        if else (Class.Method.Variable == 0)
        {
            Show.consoleDetail();
        }
    }`
```

I then want to make it so that the label shows the string instead if you get me. I know I am not doing this properly but I can't work out how exactly to do this.

Comment: `myLabel.Text = playerDetail;` or `myLabel.Text = consoleDetail`?

Comment: what are all these methods doing? Your `if..else` is not right too

Answer (score 0):

```
private void playerLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string labelText = playerLabel.Text;

    if (Class.Method.Variable == 1)
    {
        labelText = "Player";
        Show.playerDetail();
    }
    else if(Class.Method.Variable == 0)
    {
        labelText = "Console";
        Show.consoleDetail();
    }

    playerLabel.Text = labelText;
}
```

It would be better if your methods in `Show` class returned the appropriate string, so that you can do: `playerLabel.Text = Show.WhateverDetail();`. Additionally its even better if you could tie the `Show` method with the `Variable` value so that you don't have to use an if-else logic at all.

Answer (score 0):

a.  The Text property of the Label is what you want to set your `string`s to.

```
playerLabel.Text = playerDetail;

playerLabel.Text = consoleDetail;
```

b.  Your if/else method should be in the form of:

```
if (test)
{ 
} 
else if
{ 
} 
else
{ 
}
```

You don't need the `else if` bit in the middle if there are only two branches.

c.  I'm not sure about `Show.consoleDetail()` and `Show.playerDetail()`. Are 'consoleDetail()' and 'playerDetail()' method calls?